# Need to fix broken icons in crypto chart based on vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, cryptocurrency

I'm using a Vue Js cryptocurrency chart which displays the latest prices of a list of cryptocurrencies, the problem is that there are a lot of icons links that are broken, but it's not like I can fix them individually, they're all retrieved from a github iconbase. Is there any way I can fix that or at least set a default "No image" icon to show up where there's no icon?

Part responsible for retrieving the icons:

```
// vue instance
new Vue({
  // mount point
  el: '#app',

  // app data
  data: {
    endpoint : 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/!ticker@arr',
    iconbase : 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rainner/binance-watch/master/public/images/icons/',
    cache    : {},             // coins data cache
    coins    : [],             // live coin list from api
    asset    : 'USDT',          // filter by base asset pair
    search   : '',             // filter by search string
    sort     : 'assetVolume',  // sort by param
    order    : 'desc',         // sort order ( asc, desc )
    limit    : 50,             // limit list 
    status   : 0,              // socket status ( 0: closed, 1: open, 2: active, -1: error )
    sock     : null,           // socket inst
    cx       : 0,
    cy       : 0,
  },
```

My full Js:

```
// common number filters
Vue.filter( 'toFixed', ( num, asset ) => {
  if ( typeof asset === 'number' ) return Number( num ).toFixed( asset );
  return Number( num ).toFixed( ( asset === 'USDT' ) ? 3 : 8 );
});
Vue.filter( 'toMoney', num => {
  return Number( num ).toFixed( 0 ).replace( /./g, ( c, i, a ) => {
    return i && c !== "." && ( ( a.length - i ) % 3 === 0 ) ? ',' + c : c;
  });
});

// component for creating line chart
Vue.component( 'linechart', {
  props: {
    width: { type: Number, default: 400, required: true },
    height: { type: Number, default: 40, required: true },
    values: { type: Array, default: [], required: true },
  },
  data() {
    return { cx: 0, cy: 0 };
  },
  computed: {
    viewBox() {
      return '0 0 '+ this.width +' '+ this.height;
    },
    chartPoints() {
      let data = this.getPoints();
      let last = data.length ? data[ data.length - 1 ] : { x: 0, y: 0 };
      let list = data.map( d => ( d.x - 10 ) +','+ d.y );
      this.cx  = last.x - 5;
      this.cy  = last.y;
      return list.join( ' ' );
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getPoints() {
      this.width  = parseFloat( this.width ) || 0;
      this.height = parseFloat( this.height ) || 0;
      let min     = this.values.reduce( ( min, val ) => val < min ? val : min, this.values[ 0 ] );
      let max     = this.values.reduce( ( max, val ) => val > max ? val : max, this.values[ 0 ] );
      let len     = this.values.length;
      let half    = this.height / 2;
      let range   = ( max > min ) ? ( max - min ) : this.height;
      let gap     = ( len > 1 ) ? ( this.width / ( len - 1 ) ) : 1;
      let points  = [];

      for ( let i = 0; i < len; ++i ) {
        let d = this.values[ i ];
        let val = 2 * ( ( d - min ) / range - 0.5 );
        let x = i * gap;
        let y = -val * half * 0.8 + half;
        points.push( { x, y } );
      }
      return points;
    }
  },
  template: `
  <svg :viewBox="viewBox" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polyline class="cryptocolor" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" :points="chartPoints" />
    <circle class="cryptocolor" :cx="cx" :cy="cy" r="4" fill="#fff" stroke="none" />
  </svg>`,
});

// vue instance
new Vue({
  // mount point
  el: '#app',

  // app data
  data: {
    endpoint : 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/!ticker@arr',
    iconbase : 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rainner/binance-watch/master/public/images/icons/',
    cache    : {},             // coins data cache
    coins    : [],             // live coin list from api
    asset    : 'USDT',          // filter by base asset pair
    search   : '',             // filter by search string
    sort     : 'assetVolume',  // sort by param
    order    : 'desc',         // sort order ( asc, desc )
    limit    : 50,             // limit list 
    status   : 0,              // socket status ( 0: closed, 1: open, 2: active, -1: error )
    sock     : null,           // socket inst
    cx       : 0,
    cy       : 0,
  },

  // computed methods
  computed: {

    // process coins list
    coinsList() {
      let list = this.coins.slice();
      let search = this.search.replace( /[^\s\w\-\.]+/g, '' ).replace( /[\r\s\t\n]+/g, ' ' ).trim();

      if ( this.asset ) {
        list = list.filter( i => i.asset === this.asset );
      }
      if ( search && search.length > 1 ) {
        let reg = new RegExp( '^('+ search +')', 'i' );
        list = list.filter( i => reg.test( i.token ) );
      }
      if ( this.sort ) {
        list = this.sortList( list, this.sort, this.order );
      }
      if ( this.limit ) {
        list = list.slice( 0, this.limit );
      }
      return list;
    },

    // show socket connection loader
    loaderVisible() {
      return ( this.status === 2 ) ? false : true;
    },

    // sort-by label for buttons, etc
    sortLabel() {
      switch ( this.sort ) {

        case 'token'       :  return 'Token';
        case 'percent'     :  return 'Percent';
        case 'close'       :  return 'Price';
        case 'change'      :  return 'Change';
        case 'assetVolume' :  return 'Volume';
        case 'tokenVolume' :  return 'Volume';
        case 'trades'      :  return 'Trades';
        default            :  return 'Default';
      }
    },
  },

  // custom methods
  methods: {

    // apply sorting and toggle order
    sortBy( key, order ) {
      if ( this.sort !== key ) { this.order = order || 'asc'; }
      else { this.order = ( this.order === 'asc' ) ? 'desc' : 'asc'; }
      this.sort = key;
    },

    // filter by asset
    filterAsset( asset ) {
      this.asset = String( asset || 'BTC' );
    },

    // set list limit
    setLimit( limit ) {
      this.limit = parseInt( limit ) || 0;
    },

    // on socket connected
    onSockOpen( e ) {
      this.status = 1; // open
      console.info( 'WebSocketInfo:', 'Connection open ('+ this.endpoint +').' );
    },

    // on socket closed
    onSockClose( e ) {
      this.status = 0; // closed
      console.info( 'WebSocketInfo:', 'Connection closed ('+ this.endpoint +').' );
      setTimeout( this.sockInit, 10000 ); // try again
    },

    // on socket error
    onSockError( err ) {
      this.status = -1; // error
      console.error( 'WebSocketError:', err.message || err );
      setTimeout( this.sockInit, 10000 ); // try again
    },

    // process data from socket
    onSockData( e ) {
      let list = JSON.parse( e.data ) || [];

      for ( let item of list ) {
        // cleanup data for each coin
        let c = this.getCoinData( item );
        // keep to up 100 previous close prices in hostiry for each coin
        c.history = this.cache.hasOwnProperty( c.symbol ) ? this.cache[ c.symbol ].history : this.fakeHistory( c.close );
        if ( c.history.length > 100 ) c.history = c.history.slice( c.history.length - 100 );
        c.history.push( c.close );
        // add coin data to cache
        this.cache[ c.symbol ] = c;
      }
      // convert cache object to final prices list for each symbol
      this.coins = Object.keys( this.cache ).map( s => this.cache[ s ] );
      this.status = 2; // active
    },

    // start socket connection
    sockInit() {
      if ( this.status > 0 ) return;
      try {
        this.status = 0; // closed
        this.sock = new WebSocket( this.endpoint );
        this.sock.addEventListener( 'open', this.onSockOpen );
        this.sock.addEventListener( 'close', this.onSockClose );
        this.sock.addEventListener( 'error', this.onSockError );
        this.sock.addEventListener( 'message', this.onSockData );
      }
      catch( err ) {
        console.error( 'WebSocketError:', err.message || err );
        this.status = -1; // error
        this.sock = null;
      }
    },

    // start socket connection
    sockClose() {
      if ( this.sock ) {
        this.sock.close();
      }
    },

    // come up with some fake history prices to fill in the initial line chart
    fakeHistory( close ) {
      let num = close * 0.0001; // faction of current price
      let min = -Math.abs( num );
      let max = Math.abs( num );
      let out = [];

      for ( let i = 0; i < 50; ++i ) {
        let rand = Math.random() * ( max - min ) + min;
        out.push( close + rand );
      }
      return out;
    },

    // finalize data for each coin from socket
    getCoinData( item ) {
      let reg         = /^([A-Z]+)(BTC|ETH|BNB|USDT|TUSD)$/;
      let symbol      = String( item.s ).replace( /[^\w\-]+/g, '' ).toUpperCase();
      let token       = symbol.replace( reg, '$1' );
      let asset       = symbol.replace( reg, '$2' );
      let name        = token;
      let pair        = token +'/'+ asset;
      let icon        = this.iconbase + token.toLowerCase() + '_.png';
      let open        = parseFloat( item.o );
      let high        = parseFloat( item.h );
      let low         = parseFloat( item.l );
      let close       = parseFloat( item.c );
      let change      = parseFloat( item.p );
      let percent     = parseFloat( item.P );
      let trades      = parseInt( item.n );
      let tokenVolume = Math.round( item.v );
      let assetVolume = Math.round( item.q );
      let sign        = ( percent >= 0 ) ? '+' : '';
      let arrow       = ( percent >= 0 ) ? '▲' : '▼';
      let info        = [ pair, close.toFixed( 8 ), '(', arrow, sign + percent.toFixed( 2 ) +'%', '|', sign + change.toFixed( 8 ), ')' ].join( ' ' );
      let style       = '';

      if ( percent > 0 ) style = 'gain';
      if ( percent < 0 ) style = 'loss';

      return { symbol, token, asset, name, pair, icon, open, high, low, close, change, percent, trades, tokenVolume, assetVolume, sign, arrow, style, info };
    },

    // sort an array by key and order
    sortList( list, key, order ) {
      return list.sort( ( a, b ) => {
        let _a = a[ key ];
        let _b = b[ key ];

        if ( _a && _b ) {
          _a = ( typeof _a === 'string' ) ? _a.toUpperCase() : _a;
          _b = ( typeof _b === 'string' ) ? _b.toUpperCase() : _b;

          if ( order === 'asc' ) {
            if ( _a < _b ) return -1;
            if ( _a > _b ) return 1;
          }
          if ( order === 'desc' ) {
            if ( _a > _b ) return -1;
            if ( _a < _b ) return 1;
          }
        }
        return 0;
      });
    },
  },

  // app mounted
  mounted() {
    this.sockInit();
  },

  // app destroyed
  destroyed() {
    this.sockClose();
  }
});
```

Js Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/g5mhe923/1/

My version is from this modification:
https://codepen.io/rainner/pen/bjJYjp

Original source code:
https://github.com/rainner/binance-watch

Js files from the updated version:
https://rainner.github.io/binance-watch/public/bundles/app.min.js
https://rainner.github.io/binance-watch/public/js/crypto-js.min.js

Original demo:
https://rainner.github.io/binance-watch/

Can anyone tell me where I can find a reference to this part?

I couldn't find any reference to this part too:

```
// app data
  data: {
    endpoint : 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/!ticker@arr',
    iconbase : 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rainner/binance-watch/master/public/images/icons/',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know 2 tricks for broken link images:

1. The first is to hide the images with broken link:

```html
    <img :src="c.icon" :alt="c.pair" onerror="this.style.display='none'"/>
```

2. The second is to use a default image from your choice and display it in case the image link is broken. Like the following where I took one of your images as a default image

```html
   <img :src="c.icon" :alt="c.pair" onerror="this.src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rainner/binance-watch/master/public/images/icons/xtz_.png'" />
```

[Here is a Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fdgdfgdd/5fqmj1ze/5/)

Comment: I'm trying to set an image, but it's not working `<img :src="c.icon" :alt="c.pair" onerror="this.style.background='url('/123/crypto-nopic.png')'"/>` . Also, I'd prefer to know how to settle the `iconbase :` URL.

Comment: So that can't be done inside the javascript file, right? Please shed me some light before I just give up on this. I wanted to least understand that Binance API, since I couldn't find a reference anywhere to this "iconbase" part here:
`let icon        = this.iconbase + token.toLowerCase() + '_.png';`

Comment: I couldn't find any reference to this part too:
`// app data
  data: {
    endpoint : 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/!ticker@arr',
    iconbase : 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rainner/binance-watch/master/public/images/icons/',`